# SQL Server Update Locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, sql-update, read-uncommitted

If you have the following sql, is it possible that if it is run multiple times by many different processes at exactly the same time, that two or more processes may update the table?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
UPDATE table
SET Column1 = 1
WHERE Column1 = 0
```

No other locks etc are specified in the sql, other that Read Uncommitted.

I'm trying to track down an issue, and I'm now clutching at straws...

Comment: did you get a chance to read my reply, or if you find any more interesting answer, please update :) .

Answer (score 0):

Got this from MSDN.

Transactions running at the READ UNCOMMITTED level do not issue shared locks to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction. READ UNCOMMITTED transactions are also not blocked by exclusive locks that would prevent the current transaction from reading rows that have been modified but not committed by other transactions. When this option is set, it is possible to read uncommitted modifications, which are called dirty reads. Values in the data can be changed and rows can appear or disappear in the data set before the end of the transaction. This option has the same effect as setting NOLOCK on all tables in all SELECT statements in a transaction. This is the least restrictive of the isolation levels.

So basically, this is equivalent to SQL Server , NOLOCK hint. This might result in dirty reads, i.e. if some process in updated 1000 records and updated 500 till now, and other process read  that data, then data might be in inconsistent form. This also helps in executing update without getting blocked (shared lock) by multiple select queries.

Hope this make some sense to your question. For reference -- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173763.aspx)